# Is there any gameplay benefit to finding all the manuscript pages in Alan Wake?

Tags: alan-wake

Achievements notwithstanding, is there any gameplay benefit to finding all the manuscript pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No unlockables. However if you read them as you go, they do foreshadow certain events...